# Can Tier 2 General UK visa holders travel to Ireland without an Irish visa

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, ireland

I have a Tier 2 General UK visa which is valid until 2019. Can I travel to Ireland (Dublin, Belfast) without an Irish visa? It would be for a short holiday.

Comment: This is only for a Holiday (2-5 days)

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Also the Isle of Man and the Islands are fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need a visa to enter the Republic of Ireland unless you are in a [visa exempt nationality](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-required-countries).

As a general rule UK visas and leave to enter or remain in the UK are not valid for Ireland as it's a different country. Certain holders of UK visas qualify for a [visa waiver](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Irish%20Short%20Stay%20Visa%20Waiver%20Programme) but that's limited to certain nationalities, and according to the Irish immigration authorities only applies to short-stay UK visas.

You could take a trip to Northern Ireland on you visa as this does not involve leaving the UK.